# Multiple Drop-down Selections Disable Other Drop-down Menus and Options

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have two issues with my drop-down menus; first issue is that I need multiple options to either hide or show a following drop-down menu.

Each drop down menu option has multiple tasks already such as loading an image into a div and supplying a model number into a span. That action is being controlled by the option's value.

I also need various options within a drop=down to hide or show a following drop-down based on their individual values.

Here is a drop-down I currently have:

```
<select name="GlassType" id="GlassType">
  <option value="">Select Option</option>
  <option value="CL">Clear</option>
  <option value="FR">Clear Frosted</option>
  <option value="CT">Clear Textured</option>
  <option value="LI">Low Iron</option>
  <option value="LF">Low Iron Frosted</option>
  <option value="LT">Low Iron Textured</option>
</select>
```

The value attached to these options are linked to displaying their own image into a div and their own code into the span.

I have been able to achieve this with one value, but not multiple values.

The second issue I have is that I need half of these to disable options, not the menu, in a 3rd drop down. I have not found a solution for this.

[Here is my Fiddle thus far](https://jsfiddle.net/tyky1fzj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct that when for example you select Model = FP209, you want to disable some of the options in the Glass Thickness dropdown?

I've added just these 4 lines so when you select model FP209, it will remove the third option in the Glass Thickness dropdown. Before that, it will show all previously hidden options. This will come helpful when you have multiple items that will be hidden/shown.

```
list.onchange = function() {
ModelSerial.innerHTML = this.value;

if (this.value == "FP209") {
    $("#GThickness option").show();
    $("#GThickness option:nth-of-type(3)").hide();
}
```

Comment: That looks great for my second issue. Is there a way to hide more than one option? For instance, if I choose the FP209 and I want to hide certain hardware finishes like options 2, 4, and 6.
Also, you have in your code if (this.value == "FP209"). Is it possible to do something like ...== "FP209, LP204")?